# Advert layout incorrectly opening from modal

Tags: ios, ipad, modal-dialog, admob

I've taken over development of an iPad app and am adding AdMob into it, this is all working correctly apart from one layout issue when the advert opens, I believe it may be to do with it opening from a modal window.

The advert opens with some content from the previous window infront of it, it covers the status bar, and leaves a space at the bottom about the same height as the status bar. I'm adding this advert in the same way I am the others, which work from...

```
GADAdSize customAdSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(300, 50));
adView = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:customAdSize];
adView.adUnitID = @"xxxxxxxxxxxx";
adView.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:adView];
[adView setDelegate: self];
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed, without restructuring the app so the previous one isn't a modal window?
[image: This is how it looks when the advert opens]

Answer (score 0):

Are you hiding the status bar before you display the initial modal view? I know the click through modal for AdMob usually gets off-place if you do this.

Make sure you're also not doing anything else weird with positioning when you display your first modal.